# Groovy get object within json slurper object with string

Tags: java, json, groovy, katalon-studio, jsonslurper

I'm trying create a function in which I pass a json object from `JsonSlurper` and a string which contains json object located in the original. If it does, it returns true or false if the elements count condition is satisfied. For example:

myJson:

```
{
  "Errors": [],
  "Loans": [
    {
      "Applications": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "test"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Applications": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "test3"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "test3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My method would get the json array as follows:

```
def myJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(receivedResponse.responseBodyContent)
def result = verifyElementsCountGreaterThanEqualTo(myJson, "Loans[0].Applications[1]", 3)
```

Is there such a library that can do this for me?

I've tried `myJson["Loans[0].Applications[1]"]` to get the Json Object so I can get the size, but the result is `null`.

Comment: `myJson["Loans"]`

Comment: does not work for me.

Comment: Then please add what you have already tried to the question and also the errors you get.

Comment: What does `println(myJson.inspect())` give you?

Comment: @cfrick what would you recommend in the case like `myMethod(myJson, "Loans.Applications[1]");` ? This doesnt work when I try it. I get a `null`.

Comment: @usr4896260, please check below answer to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, I was able to find a solution with the rest assured [api](http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/json-path/3.1.1/io/restassured/path/json/JsonPath.html).

I'm able to use a `string` for the path I'm looking for in the Json object as follows:

```
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath as JsonPath

def myJson = "{'Errors':[],'Loans':[{'Applications':[{'id':1,'name':'test'}]},{'Applications':[{'id':2,'name':'test3'},{'id':3,'name':'test3'}]}]}"    
def applicationData = JsonPath.with(myJson).get("Loans[0].Applications[1]")
def applicationsListData = JsonPath.with(myJson).get("Loans[0].Applications")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about the following? And it is trivial, I guess.

`Loans` is a list where you get multiple `Applications`. Just pass the index of the Applications.

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonString)
//Closure to get the particular Loan
def getLoanAt = { json.Loans[it]}
//Call above closure as method to print the 2nd Applications
​println getLoanAt(1)​
```

In case if you want to print all loan applications, here you do not need closure at all:

```
json.Loans.each {println it}​
```

Here is online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/WA0uMD)</kbd> for quick test.

In case, if you want a loan application by Id, use below:

```
//To get all loan application by Id
def getApplicationById = {id -> json.Loans.Applications.flatten().find{id == it.id}}
println getApplicationById(3)
```

Quick <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/nXdgPn)</kbd> of the above.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `string` to get the data? Even with some other library? Ideally, would want something like `json."Loan.Applications[1]"` where `"Loan.Applications[1]"` would be a string parameter in my method.

Comment: @usr4896260, there are 3 approaches mentioned in the above solution. Can't you afford / feasible to apply any of those?

Comment: What exactly you want to extract from above data? The above provides what you have mentioned i.e., `getLoanAt` is similar to (just named it appropriately) instead of `myMethod`.

Comment: I've updated the description. Basically I want to call a method like this `verifyElementsCountGreaterThanEqualTo(myJson, "Loans.Applications[1]", 3)` The requirement is that "Loans.Applications[1]" is the path to the json object. It must be a string so I can reuse the function across different json results.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to convert your json to java object `Map` to be accurate, after that you can get the `Loans` as an object `ArrayList`.

```
def myJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText("{\"Errors\": [], \"Loans\": [{\"id\": 1}, {\"id\": 2}]}");
def loansList = myJson.Loans// ArrayList
```

Comment: That was my current approach. However, my actual json object contains about 50 or so fields, each with its own nesting of objects/arrays. I was looking for a function that could help make my search for such properties dynamic. I revised my description.